# Get last record from @OneToMany relationship

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I have a couple of entities with a @ManyToOne and @OneToMany relationships, and the thing is that I am looking for a way to get the last record inserted from the @OneToMany side of the relationship without loading all the records from the list, Actually, I am saving this last record in a @OneToOne relationship in ClassB, but that creates too many conflicts with FK constraints. Here is an extract of how it looks like:

```
public class ClassA {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   @ManyToOne
   public ClassB classB;
   @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
   public Date startDate;
}

public class ClassB {
   @Id
   public Long id;
   @OneToMany(mappedby = "classB", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   public List<ClassA> classAList = new ArrayList<>();
   @OneToOne
   public ClassA lastClassA; // Generates a bidirectional FK, and unable the entity for deletion.
}
```

The interaction between these classes is that `ClassA` is accumulated over time and is saved linked to `ClassB`, at the time of `ClassB` do some work, it only needs the *last* `ClassA` instance created (which would be the current `ClassA`), the previous instances of `ClassA` are not important since they are in the past now, and are only kept for history. So, because of this I created the field `lastClassA` which is updated every time a new `ClassA` is created and saved on disk.

I could also create a JPQL to get this last Record from the `classAList` field (demo bellow), but I am not sure that is the best way to do it. So, does anybody know about a strategy to get this last record without loading the entire list and selecting the last member of the list?

```
Select a from ClassA a where a.startDate = (Select MAX(b.startDate) from ClassA b where ClassB.id=:classBId)
```

Comment: I think you forgot one of the principles in IT: never change a winning team. Why looking to change a good JPA-compliant solution?

Comment: Hi @AndreiI, what do you mean exactly? what is a winning team on this context?

Comment: The solution that you have, already works and it is "the winning team".

Comment: Which one, the ()OneToOne approach or the JPQL? Because using the ()OneToOne relationship, one has to remove at least one FK in order to make it work, the entities get stuck each other with the FKs, and the JPQL seems like the best choice, since it saves space on disk (1 field less in the entity) in exchange of an additional round-trip to the database. Looks like I answered myself. What I was not sure is if there is any other method to do the same without touching the ()OneToMany relationship, I am sure somebody has have to deal with an scenario like this, since it is quite common.

Comment: I mean the OneToOne approach is a good working solution. Do not try to save space, as it is not the space your usual problem, but the performance. And I do not see any problems with that solution. Also do not try to overengineer this simple problem.

Comment: This is a very good solution and it saved my day. Thanks a lot