# How do I keep the last reference of @ManyToOne in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I want to create two class which has `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relationship. Below is a sample code.

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   public ClassB classB;

   public String something;
}

@Entity
public class ClassB {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "classB")
   public List<ClassA> classAList = new ArrayList<>();

   public String somet;
}
```

That code works just fine but, I want to have the last reference of class A in class B. I can do that by adding `@OneToOne public ClassA lastClassA;` in `ClassB` (just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222735/get-last-record-from-onetomany-relationship)). Below is the code:

```
@Entity
public class ClassA {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @ManyToOne
   public ClassB classB;

   public String something;
}

@Entity
public class ClassB {
   @Id
   public Long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedby = "classB")
   public List<ClassA> classAList = new ArrayList<>();

   @OneToOne
   public ClassA lastClassA;

   public String somet;
}
```

That code is working. The problem occurs when I insert data to either of it, I got the following error: `foreign key constraint fails`. That happened because I don't have a reference in another table.

Comment: Maybe will be better to use indexed collection mapping? Here some examples http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#collections-indexed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is  not clear exactly what you want to do however if you want a reference to the final item in the collection there are some options that could work.

1. Mark the collections as 'extra-lazy' which will allow you to access the last item in the list without loading the whole collection. If you do require to load the other items in the collection this may be problematic however.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html

> "Extra-lazy" collection fetching: individual elements of the
>   collection are accessed from the database as needed. Hibernate tries
>   not to fetch the whole collection into memory unless absolutely
>   needed. It is suitable for large collections.

2. If you only require the last item then use a Hibernate @Where clause to filter the collection

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/

3. Create a database view to filter the most recent items and map an additional entity to that.

Comment: Well I think you can achieve that using any one of the suggested methods.

Comment: yeah, I am able to do that using @Where clause. thanks